# Is my proof that an ideal comaximal to two other ideals is also comaximal to their product correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, solution-verification

*Context*: Let $R$ a commutative ring,  and $\mathfrak{a}$, $\mathfrak{b}$, $\mathfrak{b^{'}}$ are ideals.

*Problem statement*: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be comaximal to both $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{b^{'}}$. Prove that $\mathfrak{a}$ is also comaximal to $\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{b^{'}}$.

*My solution*

First, $\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{b^{'}} = \mathfrak{b} \cap \mathfrak{b^{'}}$. We can see this because all sums of the form $\sum a_i b_i$ with $a \in \mathfrak{b}, b \in \mathfrak{b^{'}}$ must be in both ideals (ideals by definition absorb multiplication and each term in this sum is the product of an element from each ideal, plus of course ideals are closed under summation). We'll need this in a second.

So, if $\mathfrak{a}$, $\mathfrak{b}$ comaximal, then for all $r \in R$ and $b \in \mathfrak{b}$, there exists some $a \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $a + b = r$.

Same thing applies for $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b^{'}}$.

So consider some $b$ in $\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{b^{'}}$. By our statement above, this element must be in both $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{b^{'}}$. By the above, for any $r \in R$, there then must exist some $a \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $a + b = r$. So $\mathfrak{b}$ and $\mathfrak{b^{'}}$ are both comaximal to $\mathfrak{a}$. ◻

The solution in my text book uses a different argument and I was just curious if mine was correct as well?

Thanks in advance!

PS - not a student, long-graduated hobbyist mathematician working through a commutative algebra text during quarantine

Comment: It isn't true in general that $\mathfrak{bb'} = \mathfrak b \cap \mathfrak b'$, even in a commutative ring; it is however true that it's a subset of it, so the proof is not impacted there.

Comment: I don't think you got the definition of comaximality right: you cannot have a, given b and r, but given r, there exist a and b

Comment: @doetoe damn. There it is. Thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

Hint for a shorter proof, if you're assuming that your ring has $1$: if $a+b=1$ and $a+b'=1$, consider $(a+b)(a+b') = a(a+b+b')+bb'$.